# Battery Ah specs vs actual Wh when charging and discharging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, energy, efficiency, battery-chemistry

It is ubiquotously stated that Wh = Ah x V. While this is true (at least regarding the units) I have some doubts about the practical aspects of it.

Using an example:

Let's take a fully discharged (0%) cell/battery and charge it at 1C during an hour (or whatever 'C' the battery can take, as long as in the end of the charge the "Ah" are correct).
Charge is done with a lossless charger and **energy delivered** is counted.

The nominal voltage of the cell "V" is a value between the 0% cell voltage and 100% cell voltage (at 0A), such that V x Ah = Wh. My guess is the "V" value of a battery is fabricated just to make this formula match in some condition (maybe full charge or full discharge or an average of both).

Let's say the charger reported 100Wh for the full charge of the cell.

If I now discharge the cell with a **lossless constant power** device at 100Wh, it will take the battery less than an hour to be at 0% again.

I believe the main issue here is that for the exact same stored electrons in a cell (stored charged), the voltage at the cell terminals will be higher when charging and lower when discharging, which yields different integration of power (different energy).

As a user concerned with efficiency, I don't care about the Coulombic efficiency (how many electrons I can put in the battery vs how many electrons I can put out), because if the transfer happens at different voltage levels, it does not tell me how much energy I am losing in this cycle.

The actual questions:

1 - Assuming the above is true (is it?), where will I see the biggest loss ratio? From integration of discharge vs charge power, from integration of discharge vs charge current, or both?
Where did the energy go? All heat inside the cell?

2 - Does the rate of charge / discharge impact these calculations, or just impacts the lifecycle of the battery on the long term?

I understand this may not be very relevant for consumer electronics, but it is crucial for understanding how much energy inside an EV battery can actually be used to move the vehicle, and which are the "real" values in the datasheet and which parameters are derived under specific conditions (such as the cell voltage).

Comment: Assume power out/in efficiency is less than unity. Losses go as heat. Datasheet always rates battery at best possible operating conditions. EV always operates at less than ideal operating conditions. Out/in efficiency is charge and discharge rate dependent, and battery temperature dependent.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Will the Ah integration out/in also be less than unity?

Comment: @ZéPedroF.A. Unless you do it perfectly, then it will be one. Have you ever seen a more gas come out of a tank than you put in?

Comment: First law: you can change energy from one form to another. Second law: you never get all of it. So, you loose some during charging and then loose some more when discharging.